# Force screen to be always on

Tags: screen, clock

We're using Samsung with Android 4.1.2 as a scrabble timer - via the default Clock application. It would be much more comfortable if I could force the phone screen to be always on so that we can see the time remaining. I found no setting or downloadable program to achieve that.

I need some workaround tip - any ideas?

Comment: After keeping an OLED screen on during the day (for development), there was a serious burn-in after 9-10 months. You may want to keep this in mind if you'll keep the screen always on. I can't comment about non-OLED screens, but my impression is that their time until burn-in is far longer.

Comment: You can have a look at this...very good reviews and should meet your needs https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chessclock.android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve a temporary solution you can go into settings -> display -> sleep -> 30 min

Find an app that supports **Keep Awake**
 *Keep Awake keeps the device unlocked and awake during the use of the app in question*

This other one will result in digging deep in to your devices settings that are normally hidden called **Developer Options** for this

- settings
- about Deice
- tap **Build Number** till you see **Developer Options Enabled**

Back out once

**Important Notice**
**Misusing and or abusing Developer Options has a chance to cause undesirable operation, and can cause apps to crash and or become unstable in turn can cause ANR (App Not Responding) messages to appear to the point of having to reset your device to factory settings. By continuing from here I am not responsible to any loss of data and or any other form of loss pertaining to the device(s) and or its data this is done on *Continue at your own risk you have been warned***

Scroll to Developer Options

- if not turned on do so at this time
     ***Please make note of the Warning***
- check **Stay Awake**
     *please note this option will only keep the device on while charging*

Comment: I used the 30 min option, that was enough for our 5 minutes timer.

Comment: That's good to hear, and I hope you had a great Christmas

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that using [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). Set up a profile with a "time" condition (specify the time frame you want the screen kept alive, e.g. "from 9 am to 6 pm", and for the task itself select "stay on". Make sure the option is disabled before starting this. [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) will then take care for it: Switching the option on at 9 am, and returning to the *previous state* at 6 pm (which is why you should have switched that option off to begin with).

Optionally, you could also define an "exit task" to explicilty switch that option off again − regardless of what it was set to in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

There's a highly-rated Play Store app named **Caffeine** *by Syntaxa* which prevents sleep by manual toggle, device plugged in, and per-app.

Compatibility from 2.2 Froyo to 5.1 Lollipop.

It has a 4.5 star rating and 1,355 reviews (as of April 2016)

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.syntaxa.caffeine

Answer (score 1):

The [free Android automation app Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) has a building block for [keeping the device awake](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/device_keep_awake.html), it can also keep the Wi-Fi awake in *High performance* mode.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options

1. **App based**: [Stay Alive! Keep Screen Awake](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.synetics.stay.alive). App description says

> Keep your screen on when your device is running your GPS application, favorite remote control, playing a movie or slideshow, etc... Perfect to keep your screen on without dimming for application development. Your screen will never go back to sleep until you want it to...

2. **Xposed Module**: requires root. [NeverSleep](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.hamzah.neversleep)
3. **Automation app**: [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). If this is the preferred option can revert with solution